# VBA - Calculate difference in days between two Date Values in columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a script where i can calculate the difference in days between two Date Values `Column A` and `Column B` if the `Day Value` is greater than 15 tag it as `"15 days!"`. if less than no action done..

Example:

```
Column A0 | Column B   | Column C |
01/2/2016 | 01/17/2016 |          |
01/3/2016 | 01/05/2016 |          |
01/4/2016 | 01/20/2016 |          |
```

Output:

```
 Column A0 | Column B   | Column C |
 01/2/2016 | 01/17/2016 | 15 days! |
 01/3/2016 | 01/05/2016 |          |
 01/4/2016 | 01/20/2016 | 15 days! |
```

My code:

```
Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
 Dim result As Integer

    Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)

        firstDate = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        secondDate = Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If result = DateDiff("d", firstDate, secondDate) > 15 Then
    Sheet2.Cells(result, 3) = 15 days!

  End If
```

I understand i need to use DateDiff function to calculate the days but I'm still confused on how to get the values from `column A` to `column B` use and use it as `firstdate` ,`second date` values. can someone help me about this?!

Comment: There is no VBA code necessary. A simple formula will do: `=If(B2-A2>15,"15 days!", "")`. Put this formula into cell `C2` and copy the formula down.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for the quick reply, i'm sorry but i need it as vba code im doing a generated report so....

Comment: If you want to do it with VBA then you'll have to implement a loop to iterate through the rows and calculate each date difference 1 by 1: http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html Of course, this would be faster if you were to do this in an array and then just write back the results to the sheet: http://www.homeandlearn.org/arrays_and_loops.html BTW, you don't need to use `DateDiff` for days. Just grab from column A and column B  the `.Value2` and then calculate the difference. The result will be automatically in days: `Sheet2.Range("B2").Value2 - Sheet2.Range("A2").Value2`.

Comment: @ Ralph thanks for the links i'm going to try it :)

Comment: @Ralph can you show a sample code?

Comment: You have already an accepted answer. Isn't the code working for you? What else do you need? Is there a new question? If so, please post / open a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub CalculateDate()
Dim Result, RowNo As Long
Dim FirstDate, SecondDate As Date
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

RowNo = 1

    Do Until ws.Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""

    FirstDate = ws.Cells(RowNo, 1)
    SecondDate = ws.Cells(RowNo, 2)

        If DateDiff("d", FirstDate, SecondDate) >= 15 Then
        ws.Cells(RowNo, 3) = "15 DAYS!"
        End If

    RowNo = RowNo + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: wow! suddenly it's magic! thanks @Brendan Gooden :)
does RowNo, 1 RowNo, 2 means Column A and B right? and will calculate dates in any format right?

Comment: That's correct! The `Cells` format is like so `Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)` e.g. `Cells(1, 1)` is the same as saying `Range("A1")`   or, use a variable for the row, like we have done - `Cells(RowNo, 1)`